# 301 redirect with query string - woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is the problem I've stalled for days. 
My setup is Wordpress with Woocommerce installed. Permalinks structure works great, so I just need to redirect old URLs to the new ones.

Old url structure looks like this:
`http://domain.tld/?product=bla-bla`

But I need them to redirect like this:
`http://domain.tld/product/bla-bla`

*bla-bla is dynamic part.

The rule in .htaccess I've made:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /product/%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

But the result is partially wrong:
`http://domain.tld/product/bla-bla?product=bla-bla`

The contents of the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /product/%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /product/%1? [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

`?` at the end of target will strip off any query string from original URL.